# WCF set up on iis

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I'm getting the following error when I try to browse a web service that i added on IIS 7.
When I go to content view i can browse the end points."HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory".

If it is related to giving user permissions to an III user, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

This just means you have tried to browse the WCF service without the service file.

You need to browse to MyService.svc, for example, not just to the directory that contains it.

Comment: Im new to wcf, but if i browse the site, is it not suppose to list all the services available.

Comment: On the asp.net site, what is your "home" page? For example `Default.aspx`. Whatever this page is needs to be listed under the default pages in IIS (it normally contains things like `index.html` and `default.aspx` as default, but if your home page is `home.aspx` it won't be know to IIS as a start page.)